# Are there hooks for WordPress updates?

Tags: plugins, hooks, updates

Pretty much a newbie to WordPress here but was wondering if there are any hooks or anything that could be used to send a notification out if either a WordPress update fails or a plugin update fails?

Preferably both if possible but definitely the main core of WordPress being updated.

I noticed there are a couple of plugins for WordPress which allow you to send notifications to emails or Slack channels depending on certain actions happening on a site. Most of these are to do with new posts or comments to posts and so on and so forth though.

One of the plugins allows you to specify a 'hook' which when it fires will send a notification to a Slack channel so I was wondering is there any way of plugging into this in any way when an update of any sort fails?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a hook you can use, it's called [`upgrader_process_complete`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete). This hook fires after plugins or core has been upgraded.

You can hook to this action and send an email:

```
function send_custom_email( $object, $options ) {
    // Get the path for plugins
    $plugin_path = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
    // Check if the plugin is upgraded
    if ($options['type'] == 'plugin' && $options['action'] == 'update' ){
        foreach($options['packages'] as $plugin){
            if ($plugin == $plugin_path){
            // Do some stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'send_custom_email',10, 2);
```

This function allows you to do whatever you want whenever a plugin is updated. You can do so with the core updates, too.

Comment: Hi Jack. Many thanks for that. Just wondering if there's a way to use this so that if an update fails to get a notification or is that what this code does do already? Sorry my coding skills aren't fantastic and so don't totally understand everything in the above code.

Comment: @MarkBowen Hi! You're welcome. If you aren't familiar with coding, you can use [WP Update Notifier](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-updates-notifier/) plugin. It hasn't been updated for a while, but based on user ratings it appears that it's compatible with the recent WordPress versions.